# analogWrite for LED_BUILTIN does not work

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to make the LED on the Wemos D1 mini R2 ESP8266 light up gradually.

I try this code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    analogWrite(LED_BUILTIN, i);
    delay(10);
  }

  for (int i = 200; i > 0; i--){
    analogWrite(LED_BUILTIN, i);
    delay(10);
  }

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  delay (2000);
}
```

And it does not work. I changed LED_BUILTIN to D3 and it works, but when I changed LED_BUILTIN to D4, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Does the LED light up at all?  Does it flash?  Is the pin you're using even capable of analog output, or only digital?  Please clarify.

Comment: Is there even a LED wired to D4?

Comment: @OregonJim the LED_BUILTIN remain bright permanently in both situations ( pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);pinMode(D4, OUTPUT) )

Comment: @greg_gor when I set pinMode(D4, OUTPUT) and connect an external LED to pin D4, the external LED works correctly but LED_BUILTIN remains bright permanently

Answer (score 2):

analogWrite command is for sending pwm signal in different duty-cycle
as far as I know the built_in led is not capable of working in pwm mode just regular on-off

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the LED is wired to D3.